# RCU, WCU, partition keys configuration for DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, partitioning

I'm new to DynamoDb and unable to decide how to choose my partition keys. The documentation states that pick the column with high cardinality but this will essentially mean that lot of partitions wont be accessed. Which in turn will lead to WCU and RCU not being used in their full capacity.

For example, in case of Movie database, I'm guessing I should use language/director name as partition key and movie id as sort key. This will keep things balanced out. Or should I use movie id as partition key. Is my understanding wrong over here?

Can someone please guide me what should be the correct approach and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some searching and found an explanation. I wished AWS documentation had this.

Firstly, there is no one to one mapping between partition and partition keys. DynamoDb starts with one partition and stores everything in there and once it fills up (limit is 10GB) it breaks it down into 2 partitions. At this time it takes all the partition keys and divide them equally in both the partitions.

For eg. if user_id is the partition key, Partition 1 may have user_id's 1,4,6 and Partition 2 will have user_id's 2,3,5. DynamoDb doesn't necessarily divide partition keys in sequential order. Hence when a query is executed it can go to either partition not clogging one.

Below is also the url of a blog which explains this in more detail and pictorial representation. In case someone wants to read about this in depth. **ONE NOTE** though, few technical details have changed as the blog is of 2017 but conceptually it explains what exactly is happening.

https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/partitioning-behavior-of-dynamodb

Comment: Consider edit and improve your answer as link-only answers are generally considered as low quality answer. [It would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.